# Python Selecting a number from the right side

Tags: python, dataframe

I am looking to write a python function that will select a number. So 
For example, for n=1234567 and k=3, the program has to print the digit 5. So K would define the digit to select from the right side. If the program has less than K digits it will just print 0 instead. So if N = 12 K= 3 it will print 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can use negative numbers as the index in a list to select from the back. So for example if you have the following list: `l = [0, 1, 2, 3]` then `l[1]` would be `1` and `l[-1]` would be `3`.

In your case you can convert your number to a string, and then treat it like a list. So the solution would be:

```
k = 2
n = 12345
n = str(n) # Convert it to string to be able to treat it as list.
results = int(n[-k]) # This would be 4. We have to convert it back to int.
```

Comment: o wow great thank you so much. I was stuck and going nowhere I had to begin with this thanks for the help I think I am able to get the  rest of it working now!

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark my answer as the correct one. Happy to help!